# How to pass selected item data from JComboBox to another JFrame class?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I'm working on a college project, it involves selecting a user from a list and "logging in".  I currently get the data from the database and use a while loop to add the data to the JComboBox:

```
while(rs.next())
{
    userID = rs.getInt("user_ID");
    fname = rs.getString("fname");
    lname = rs.getString("lname");
    userSelect.addItem(userID + " " + fname + " " + lname);

}
```

I then want to pass the userID of the selected item to the new JFrame and just the userID.  From there I can get the rest of the information of the user.  What would be the best way to approach it?  To splice the string?

I have a submit button that runs the following

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == select) {
        Object item = userSelect.getSelectedItem();
        System.out.println(item);
        UserDash getDash = new UserDash(item);
        this.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to seperate the presentation of the data from the data/model.  `JComboBox` is very flexible in this respect.  Start by having a look at [How to Use Combo Boxes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) and [Providing a Custom Renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer) in particular (this is a very common concept in Swing and one you should get to know).

Comment: This then means you can rely on a "model" representation of he user (ie a object) and not rely on `String` parsing, which is almost always the worst thing you can do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just an update to my question from yesterday.  I used the following to be able to pass data from a JComboBox to another JFrame

```
public SelectUser()  {
    // Database Connection & Query Code Here
    while(rs.next())
    {
        Integer userID = rs.getInt("user_ID");
        String fname = rs.getString("fname");
        String lname = rs.getString("lname");
        item = new Object[] {userID, fname, lname};
        userSelect.addItem(new Item(userID, fname, lname));

    }
    private class Item {
        private int userID;
        private String fname;
        private String lname;

        public Item(Integer userID, String fname, String lname) {
            this.userID = userID;
            this.fname = fname;
            this.lname = lname;
        }

        public Integer getUserID() {
            return userID;
        }

        public String getFName() {
            return fname;
        }

        public String getLName() {
            return lname;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ID: " + getUserID() + " " + getFName() + " " + getLName();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == select) {
            Item item = (Item) userSelect.getSelectedItem();
            System.out.println(item.getUserID() + " " + item.getFName() + " " + item.getLName());
            UserDash runDash = new UserDash(item.getUserID(), item.getFName(), item.getLName());
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps anyone looking to do the same or something similar!